# Can't select the database when updating EF model

Tags: entity-framework, updatemodel, edmx-designer

I have an edmx model

I right click on it and select **Update model from database**

The wizard show up .It normally show me **Choose Your Data Connexion**, but not anymore. Now it show me directly **Choose Your Database Objects**

How can I select a different database ?

**PS**: When I create a second edmx in the same project and want to update it, the second one works like it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trials, I found it.

You must delete the connection string in your config file (app.config in my case)